# PostgreSQL and PHP. Fetching from query adds space to char string

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, fetch

I have a table with a few fields. One field is `char[128]`. Now i store there a string `'hello'`. 
Now. In PHP i call: `arr = pg_fetch_array(pg_query('select * from table'))` but when I get value from this column i get `'hello '`. When I execute `'select char_length(this_field) from table'` using pgAdmin then I get value 5 not 6. Do you know why there is an extra space in PHP there?

Using `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR` solves this problem.

Comment: Don't use `char` it hardly ever makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

padding to the length is documented:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

> character(n), char(n) fixed-length, blank padded

example:

```
t=# with c(t) as (values('abc'::char(3)),('a'::char(3)))
select t,concat(t,'.') from c;
  t  | concat
-----+--------
 abc | abc.
 a   | a  .
(2 rows)
```

regarding length:

```
t=# with c(t) as (values('abc'::char(3)),('a'::char(3)))
select t,concat(t,'.'),octet_length(t),char_length(t) from c;
  t  | concat | octet_length | char_length
-----+--------+--------------+-------------
 abc | abc.   |            3 |           3
 a   | a  .   |            3 |           1
(2 rows)
```

using `character varying` or `text` indeed changes this behaviour.